# PDF conditioned on a a variable

Tags: probability, normal-distribution

I have this proceses
 $\sum_{n=0}^{N/2-1} z(n)$
where 
\begin{equation}\label{eq:z(n)}
z(n) = \begin{cases}
z_1(n), & \textrm{if} \, \mathtt{p}=0 ;\\
-(z_1(n)+z_2(n))/\sqrt{2} , & \textrm{otherwise}.
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

$\mathtt{p}$ is a random variable that depends on $z(n)$. For instance to find $P\text(\mathtt{p}=0)$:

$\tilde{s} _1=\dot{s}+z_1(n)$ and 
$\tilde{s} _2=\dot{s}+z_2(n)$

\begin{align}P_c( 2\tilde{s} _2<\tilde{s} _1\cap \tilde{s} _1=\mathtt{s}\vert \dot{s}>0) 
&=P( 2\tilde{s} _2<\tilde{s} _1)P(\tilde{s} _1=\mathtt{s}\vert \dot{s}>0) \\ \nonumber
&= f_{\tilde{s}_1} (\mathtt{s}; s_1,\sigma_1\vert \dot{s}>0) \Phi (\mathtt{s}/{2\sigma_2)},
\end{align}

\begin{align*}
P\text(\mathtt{p}=0) & = {\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}} P_c( 2\tilde{s} _2<\tilde{s} _1\cap \tilde{s} _1=\mathtt{s}\vert \dot{s}>0)  \, d\mathtt{s}.
\end{align*}

I need to find the variance of the process. Is there any ideas where I should start from?

I thought of doing the following. Let $\sigma_1^2$ be the variance of $z_1(n)$, and $\sigma_2^2$ be the variance of $-(z_1(n)+z_2(n))/\sqrt{2}$. Then the variance of $z(n)$ is
$$
P\text(\mathtt{p}=0) \sigma_1^2 + \mathbb{P}(p=1) \times \sigma_2^2
$$
The challenge in my problem is that to find $\mathtt{p}=1$ is found by $P_c( 2\tilde{s} _2>\tilde{s} _1\cap \tilde{s} _1=\mathtt{s}\vert \dot{s}>0)$ so $P_c$ can be easily found, but it is not mapped to $\tilde{s} _1=\mathtt{s}$ instead its mapped to $(\tilde{s} _1+\tilde{s} _1)/\sqrt{2}$. I know the pdf of $(\tilde{s} _1+\tilde{s} _1)/\sqrt{2}$, if that helps

Comment: Do you have more information about $P$? How does it depend on $z(n)$ and what values can it assume?

Comment: So $p$ depends on $z(n)$ and $z(n)$ depends on $p$?  This seems to be a problem.